# How to add ads (like google adsense) in my .net and Java desktop application?

Tags: java, .net, ads, adsense

How to add ads (like google adsense) in my .net and Java desktop application ?

Comment: Google's first hit answers your question.  Come on, man.

Comment: Sign up for an Google Adsense/AdMob account and try it?

Comment: @yep no it does not, because as you might not be aware, every person has UNIQUE google results that depend on their search history, preferences and location.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky: With sane keywords, they're not going to differ vastly in this scope.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I guess that means I'm insane.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846740/adsense-equivalent-for-a-desktop-application) and [this AdSense help article](http://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=113064), the Terms of Service for AdSense do not permit placement in desktop applications. Only web-based applications can be used with AdSense's license.

If you're working with a different ad provider that does allow ads in desktop applications, you can probably go so far as to download each ad's HTML from the provider and stick it in a JLabel.

Comment: is that legal? Doesnt that break any rules?

Comment: @TomasBisciak If the ad provider allows ads in desktop applications, I don't see why you couldn't display the HTML in a JLabel. You'd want to check the Terms of Service for your specific ad provider though.